# getProgress method of WebView object returning incorrect result

Tags: android, webview

I am having trouble using a `WebView` that I need to periodically update, as the application I am programming requires a real-time display.  The `WebView` needs to be updated every 600 seconds or so.  I am using the `getProgress` method of my `WebView` object in order to check if it had loaded properly, because if it does not, the `WebView` shows a blank white screen for that update period (this can get very annoying for any end user).  However, the `getProgress` method of the `WebView` object seems to be returning a result of 100 when there is only a blank screen displayed in the `WebView`.  Why is the `getProgress` method reporting incorrect information like this?